# Java partial generic specialisation and extends

Tags: java, generics

Is that possible in Java to partially specialise a generic class with the `extends` constraint? Like this one:

```
class Base<U, V extends U>
{
}

class Partial<U extends Number>
    extends Base<U, Integer> // The type Integer is not a valid substitute...
{
}
```

Is this a limitation of the Java language or just my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because `Integer` needs to extends `U`, but `U` could be `Number` or any subclass of `Number`, such as `Double`, and `Integer` certainly can't extend any subclass of `Number`.

Alternatives that do compile:

```
class Partial<V extends Integer> extends Base<Integer, V>
{
}

class Partial2<V extends Number> extends Base<Number, V> 
{
}

class Partial3<V extends Integer> extends Base<Number, V>
{
}

class Full extends Base<Integer, Integer>
{
}

class Full2 extends Base<Number, Integer>
{
}
```

Comment: This was just my misunderstanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is quite logical :  `U` extends `Number`, you cannot be sure that `U` can be a parent of `Integer`. It can be any other child of `Number` (Double, Float...).